# How can I calculate $ \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_{2}^{2+h} F(x)\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Let, say, $F(x) = \sin(x^2)$ which is continuous, therefore there exists a
 $c \in [2,2+h]$ such that $$ F(c) = \frac{1}{h}\int_{2}^{2+h} F(x)\,dx.$$

I'm trying to calculate the limit when $h$ goes to zero, which is supposed to be $\sin(2)$ but I don't see it.
Could you  explain how to calculate the limit?

Comment: Should it be $\sin 2$ ?

Comment: I think you can use L'Hopital.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you had already reached the answer (almost!). Since $F$ is continuous there is a $c$ between $2$ and $2 + h$ such that $$F(c) = \frac{1}{h}\int_{2}^{2 + h}F(x)\,dx\tag{1}$$ Now as $h \to 0$ we can see that $c \to 2$ (because $c$ lies between $2$ and $2 + h$) and since $F$ is continuous $F(c) \to F(2)$. Hence the desired answer is $F(2) = \sin 4$. There is no need to invoke the stronger result known as Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 4):

Let $g(x)$ an antiderivative of $F(x)$. You have $g'(x)=F(x)$.

With the fundamental theorem of calculus :
$$\frac{1}{h}\int_{2}^{2+h} F(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{h}[g(2+h)-g(2)]$$

So if you take the limit when $h$ tends to $0$, you recognise the definition of the derivative of $g$ in $2$.

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{1}{h}\int_{2}^{2+h} F(x)\,dx=g'(2)=F(2)$$

Comment: Do u use lopital in the calculation?

Comment: No I just use the definition of the derivative.

Comment: L'Hopital isn't necessary, but it could be applied. This limit $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\int_2^{2+h} F(x)~dx}{h}$ is of the form $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h)/g(h)$ where the top and bottom both tend to 0 as $h \to 0$. 

But the above solution is better and direct... doesn't require such a big theorem like L'Hopital.